# Move Azure Synapse DB Between Servers

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have 2 SQL servers under the same subscription in azure, both have an azure synapse DB on them. I want to move/copy one of the synapse DB's to the other server. I cannot find any documentation to do this online, all the stuff I have found refers to a normal SQL DB and the copy TSQL or the method doesn't seem to work. Can anyone refer me to an article explaining how I do this, or explain how I do this in azure?

Kind Regards

Glyn

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is going to be through restore points, similar to how you might do it with a backup file in SQL Server. You can [create a restore point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-points) either in the portal or via Powershell.

```
$SubscriptionName="<YourSubscriptionName>"
$ResourceGroupName="<YourResourceGroupName>"
$ServerName="<YourServerNameWithoutURLSuffixSeeNote>"  # Without database.windows.net
$DatabaseName="<YourDatabaseName>"
$Label = "<YourRestorePointLabel>"

Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

# Create a restore point of the original database
New-AzSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -RestorePointLabel $Label
```

Once the point is created it is possible to [restore it to a different server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-active-paused-dw#restore-an-existing-dedicated-sql-pool-formerly-sql-dw-through-powershell), again using the portal or via Powershell script. They don't need to be in the same resource group for this to work.

```
$SubscriptionName="<YourSubscriptionName>"
$ResourceGroupName="<YourResourceGroupName>"
$ServerName="<YourServerNameWithoutURLSuffixSeeNote>"  # Without database.windows.net
#$TargetResourceGroupName="<YourTargetResourceGroupName>" # uncomment to restore to a different server.
#$TargetServerName="<YourtargetServerNameWithoutURLSuffixSeeNote>"  
$DatabaseName="<YourDatabaseName>"
$NewDatabaseName="<YourDatabaseName>"

Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

# Or list all restore points
Get-AzSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName

# Get the specific database to restore
$Database = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName

# Pick desired restore point using RestorePointCreationDate "xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx xx"
$PointInTime="<RestorePointCreationDate>"

# Restore database from a restore point
$RestoredDatabase = Restore-AzSqlDatabase –FromPointInTimeBackup –PointInTime $PointInTime -ResourceGroupName $Database.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $Database.ServerName -TargetDatabaseName $NewDatabaseName –ResourceId $Database.ResourceID

# Use the following command to restore to a different server
#$TargetResourceGroupName = $Database.ResourceGroupName # for restoring to different server in same resourcegroup 
#$RestoredDatabase = Restore-AzSqlDatabase –FromPointInTimeBackup –PointInTime $PointInTime -ResourceGroupName $TargetResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetServerName -TargetDatabaseName $NewDatabaseName –ResourceId $Database.ResourceID

# Verify the status of restored database
$RestoredDatabase.status
```

This doesn't cover things like server firewall settings, so if you want those to match you'll have to move that separately. The server is Azure SQL, so guides for migrating Azure SQL firewalls should also apply to Synapse dedicated pools.

If the number of tables is small, then the copy activity in Pipelines might be a good backup option, but since it requires one activity per table, setting it up for a large database will be significantly more complex than using restore points.